# Is it possible to get String's reference name in java at runtime?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get the declaration name of an object at runtime in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854969/is-it-possible-to-get-the-declaration-name-of-an-object-at-runtime-in-java)

Is it possible to get the name of a String reference in Java at runtime?

Ex:

```
String rep="asd";
```

Here, can I get the name of the `rep` variable as 'rep'?

Comment: No, names are dissolved at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference name is nothing but the name of a variable. It is just a reference pointing to an object.

You cannot get that at runtime. Primarily because, there may be **conflict between many references** that can possibly be **pointing to that String object**, or any object for that matter.

Think of it: -

```
String str = "Rohit";
String abc = str;
```

Now, you have two references `str` and `abc` pointing the same literal `Rohit`.

So, if you want the reference at runtime. which reference will you get? That's why it is not allowed in Java. Not even through `Reflection`.

But if you want, you can maintain all your reference names manually. But that would be a tedious job. But I have one question -> `Why on earth would you need that?`

Comment: Identifier strings get converted into numerical values quite early on in the Java compilation process. The actual "name" associated with a given variable is therefore lost in the compilation. The compiler doesn't care what its' called, only where it is to be stored.

Comment: @Will. Exactly, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that if you're asking this question, you're doing something wrong.  Without more info as to what you're actually doing, the short answer is "no, it's not possible", however, if for some reason you really do need the variable name at run-time then your best best is to use a hashmap where you can look at both the key's label name as well as the value held therein.