# How to avoid magic strings in Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have following code in my application:

```
for(PropertyDescriptor property : myObjectProperties){
    if(property.getName().equals("myPropertyName")){
         // logic goes here
    }
}
```

This is of course hazardous on multiple levels, probably the worst being that if I rename the attribute "myPropertyName" on "MyObject", the code will break.

That said, what is the simplest way I could reference the name of the property without explicitly typing it out (as this would enable me to get compiler warning)? I'm looking something like:

```
for(PropertyDescriptor property : myObjectProperties){
    if(property.getName().equals(MyObject.myPropertyName.getPropertyName())){
         // logic goes here
    }
}
```

Or is this even possible with Java?

Comment: sorry but you cant do this like that, in theory you could define in each your class constant fo each your method, but i dont think it is solution here

Comment: I guess we would need more information about your code design if we are supposed to suggest improvements. What are you trying to achieve with the code? E.g. If you have the property at compile time, why would you want to access it using reflection? If you don't have it at compile time, how do you want to use a compile time reference to retrieve the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define target property, by adding some annotation to it. Then in a loop search fields that has desired annotation.

First define an annotation, that will be accessible at runtime

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Target {
}
```

nice and easy,
now create your class that uses it

```
public class PropertySearcher {

    int awesome;
    int cool;
    @Target
    int foo;
    int bar;
    String something;
}
```

now lets search for it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PropertySearcher ps = new PropertySearcher();
    for (Field f : ps.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        for (Annotation a : f.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
            if (a.annotationType().getName().equals(Target.class.getName())) {
                System.out.println("Fname= " + f.toGenericString());
                //do magic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output
`Fname= int reflection.PropertySearcher.foo`
property found.

This way you can refactor your code with no worries.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the declared names of fields from an object as multiple fields can equal the same object. Its explained better here: [Is it possible to get the declaration name of an object at runtime in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854969/is-it-possible-to-get-the-declaration-name-of-an-object-at-runtime-in-java)